# In WPF how can I bind to settings in configSections in app.config?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, visual-studio-2013

We are a tiny three person WPF shop (C#/WPF/.NET 4.0 CP), each of us still relatively new to WPF (less than a year of experience).  Our application has a lot of internal, global constants - things like background colors, brushes, pixel widths, tooltip strings - that we want to move to the app.config file.

At the same time, I would like to be able to bind - in xaml - directly to these app.config values.  Is this possible?

I'm already aware that you can access the trivial key/value pairs defined here:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="TextBlockHeight" value="50"/>
</appSettings>
```

by adding the namespace to your xaml

xmlns:p="clr-namespace:SampleApp.Properties"

and then referencing that in the body

```
<TextBlock
    Height="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=TextBlockHeight}" />
```

I didn't know about any of this capability until today, but it makes sense to me.  What I haven't found anything on is a clear description of what this is referencing

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:SampleApp.Properties"
```

Who and what is generating that **Properties** object?  And why is the Binding referencing Settings.**Default**?  What's Default?  Can there be other attributes on the Settings object?

Above and beyond this, our application is sufficiently complicated that I want to do two things:

**1.**
use config sections to separate out our configurable values according to our own internal modules

That might look like this:

```
      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="Qst2ConfigGroup">
          <section name="Qst2Settings" type="WinWam6.Qst2ConfigSection, WW6-WPF" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>
...
      <Qst2Settings
          LoadQst2Async = "true"
          AutoDisplayFirstQst2Insp = "true"
          AllowQst2ParallelLoad = "true"
          AllowMultiThread = "true"
          ShowNodeData = "true"
          ShowAllFailNotes = "true"
          ShowAllRules = "true"
          ShowAllValues = "true"
          TwipsPerPixelX = "15.0"
          TwipsPerPixelY = "15.0" />
```

**2.**
be able to pass the config sections out of the main application and down into DLLs.  The DLLs will implement some reporting features and we know from past experience that we will want the runtime values of those configuration parameters.

I'm less concerned with #2 right now, and much more interested in #1.  Is there a way to say something like this:

```
<Checkbox
        IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Qst2ConfigGroup}, Path=Qst2Settings.LoadQst2Async}" />
```

And just fyi I have dabled with this and there really is a backing class for WinWam6.Qst2ConfigSection.  I'm just not sure I'm going down the right avenue here.

Comment: Properties isn't an object; it's part of the <project>.Properties namespace. Re Default, this is part of the singleton pattern used by Microsoft. See my post on this, the complete example at the bottom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624304/singleton-pattern-default-property.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an application or library, you can see a "Properties" folder. Inside this folder, there will be Resouces.resx and Settings.settings.
When you reference to `xmlns:p="clr-namespace:SampleApp.Properties"`, it actually returns you the contents in this folder. Look into Settings.Designer.cs, you can find "SampleApp.Properties.Settings" defined here with a static property "**Default**" . This is what you want to know about **Default**.

So, actually what you are using now is defined in Settings.settings, but not in App.Config.
If you want to use the key/value pairs in App.Config, you need to use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings`. But they are all key/value pairs, you cannot use it in XAML so easily. You may need to add a TypeConverter for it.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a setting to the program, it adds the default value to the app.config & it adds a property with that name to a class defined in Settings.Designer.cs.  There are a couple of things you need to know:

1. The Settings class is static.  You can't instantiate an instance of it.
2. You can't change the value of application settings in app.config.
3. User settings can be changed, but not in app.config.  User settings get written to a file in the user's profile folder.  The app.config only holds default values.

I would create a view model class for the settings.  The class would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and would have one property for each setting that can be modified.  The getter for each setting property would retrieve the value of the property from `Settings.Default`.  The setter would set the property & raise the `PropertyChanged` event.  The save/OK button on your form would save the changes.

For example, if we had a user setting called `RootDir`, this would look something like this:

```
public class UserSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public string RootDir {
        get { return Settings.Default.RootDir; }
        set {
            Settings.Default.RootDir = value;
            OnPropertyChanged( "RootDir" );
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public OnPropertyChanged( string property ) {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler h = PropertyChanged;
            if ( h != null ) {
                h(property);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could then add a `RoutedCommand` to save the changes to the user's profile.

Answer (score 0):

I have a WPF UserControl in a Windows Forms application (VB.NET). I'm not sure if this is analogous to the situation in the question. I am able to bind controls within the user control at design time by setting the DataContext on the WPF User Control to be My.Settings. This shows up in the XAML like this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <My:MySettings/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Then when I bind properties of the controls within the WPF/XAML it shows my all my App Settings.