# Singleton Pattern - Default Property

Tags: c#, design-patterns, visual-studio-2013

I've been studying the Singleton pattern as it is used in the Settings class. Here's the relevant code from Settings.Designer.cs for my project AccessTest:

```
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase
{        
    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default
    {
        get
        {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

    public string applicationSetting1
    {
        get
        {
            return ((string)(this["applicationSetting1"]));
        }
    }
}
```

What is unclear to me is why the property 'applicationSetting1' is accessed through another property 'Default' like this:

```
var value = AccessTest.Properties.Settings.Default.applicationSetting1;
```

I'm running VS2013 C# and 4.5.

Comment: `applicationSetting1` is not `static` so it has to be accessed through an `instance`. What would you rather it look like?

Comment: Accessing through an instance would look like this:

Comment: Accessing through an instance would look like this:

    var settings = new AccessTest.Properties.Settings();
    var r = settings.applicationSetting1;

Of course, this is the preferred form:

    var value = AccessTest.Properties.Settings.Default.applicationSetting1;

To my pea-brain, accessing 'applicationSetting1' through Default implies a pecking order. But I can't see how Default is the parent of 'applicationSetting1' just because one is static and the other isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a great many posts on the singleton pattern but I couldn't find any that address this particular issue. So I thought I'd take a shot at explaining it myself using this example that I created in my secret laboratory with the help of your posts:

```
namespace MyProject.Properties                                  
{                                   
    internal class Singleton                                
    {                               

        // Create an instance of the class itself.                          
        private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();                            

        // Wrap the instance in a public property.                          
        public static Singleton Instance                            
        {                           
            get {return instance;}                      
        }                           

        // Prevent additional references from being created with a private constructor.                         
        private Singleton() { }                         

        // Create a non-static variable.                                
        public string nonStatic = "non static";                         

    }                               
}
```

We know the following about this Singleton class:

- The 'Instance' public property can only be accessed statically.
- 'nonStatic' can't be accessed statically, i.e., it can only be
  accessed via a reference.
- The private constructor prevents additional
  references from being created.

How, then, is it possible to access 'nonStatic' from outside the class?

The framework resolves the dilemma by endowing the static 'Instance' with magical powers that only exist in a singleton situation: 'Instance' becomes a "bridge" that provides access to any non-statics. Ergo, this form works:

```
var value = MyProject.Properties.Singleton.Instance.nonStatic;
```

Note: The pattern used my Microsoft in the Settings.Designer.cs file appears to not be a true singleton because the default constructor allows additional references to be created.

Answer (score 5):

Because the `defaultInstance` is static, whereas `applicationSetting1` is not.  This effectively makes `defaultInstance` your *manager* of the class instance.  When you call a static method on a class, it doesn't need instantiating,, so you know that you can maintain only a single instance of the class.

Responding to your comments:

`Default` is NOT the *parent* of applicationSetting1; `Default` is simply a global function that returns an instance of applicationSetting1.  In the case of a singleton pattern, that always happens to be the *same* instance.

*Manager* is my term.  To better describe what a singleton pattern is, think of it as a global variable with a single accessor (which I was describing as a manager, simply because it *manages* the lifecycle of the variable).

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you point me to some MSDN docs or posts that discuss this 'manager' relationship further?

Answer (score 1):

Normaly, your Default property is called Instance

So that you can call your singleton like this :

```
Settings.Instance. X FUNCTION()
```

Design Pattern by Erich Gamma is pretty solid on design pattern.  You should be able to find a PDF on the web easily :)

BTW you should also add this to your Default/Instance property

```
If(defaultInstance == null)
{
  defaultInstance = new Settings();
}
return defaultInstance
```

That way your singleton is never null and is lazy instantiated